# Sitecore Rich Text Editor broken after 6.6 upgrade

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, rich-text-editor

I've upgraded Sitecore 6.5 rev 111230 to Sitecore 6.6 rev 120918

Since the upgrade the Rich Text editor stopped working. Sitecore returns a page not found error.

I checked the config files, and they haven't changed - it is pointing to the right editor profile (I'm using Rich Text editor default).

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: What about your Telerik handlers and binaries?

Comment: This one is a good candidate to direct to support.sitecore.net

Comment: Did you really doublecheck if everythin was ok during updating? You also posted that WFFM was broken (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907774/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-designer-broken-after-upgrade). So it seems that something got wrong with you update (or some dll's has wrong references..)

Comment: The Sitecore update looked fine. No errors. That is why I cannot understand why is not working. I solved the issue with WFFM, I had to reinstall the whole module from scratch as the upgrade package didn't work (Sitecore support actually told me to do a full install of the module)

Answer (score 2):

What we normally do in a situation like that is look for obvious mistakes like: "Did we forget to put the correct .dll files in the bin folder" or compare the clean 6.6 rev. web.config with the web.config currently in your solution. Maybe you forgot one of the steps listed in the upgrade process and therefor a compare can sometimes help you address this kind of mistakes.

Comment: I run Sitecore upgrade package - all the files were copied to the bin folder. The config file points to the default editor. I changed it to a different editor but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled MVC?  I found that I had to remove the line:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

from the `RegisterRoutes` function in the `Global.asax.cs` file.